# how to extract struct from array json of string before spark2.4

Tags: json, apache-spark

source json : `["a","b",...]`

extract to dataframe :

```
+----+
| tmp|
+----+
|a   |
|b   |
+----+
```

since spark 2.4 we can use : `explode(from_json($"column_name", ArrayType(StringType)))`

it works very well
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24391

but how should I do with spark before 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

Manually parse the string as below:

```
df2.show
+-----------+
|column_name|
+-----------+
|  ["a","b"]|
+-----------+

val df3 = df2.selectExpr("""
    explode(
        split(
            replace(substr(column_name, 2, length(column_name) - 2), '\"', ''),
            ','
        )
    ) as tmp
""")

df3.show
+---+
|tmp|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,function replace works well, but I still want to find a better one which looks simple and its structure concise

Comment: @leitan that’s probably the simplest it can get. If you want a more concise solution, you need to upgrade spark.